# Embedded Docusign -Adding text tabs to Dynamic envelop without using template

Tags: docusignapi

I am unable to create Text tabs on a dynamic envelop created without a template. I am sending the PDf document as bytes to Docusign since I need to generate a unique envelop id for each recipient. I am able to generate a recipients view with the document specified. I am also able to add  signHereTabs and dateSignedTabs but not the text tabs/first name tabs. There are few places in the document where the user needs to fill in the information using text boxes. Please help with a solution to add a text tab for guided signing.

The envelop definition is as follows:

```
"<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" + 
                    "<emailSubjectxxx</emailSubject>" +
                    "<status>sent</status>" +                       
                    "<documents>" +
                            "<document>" + 
                            "<documentId>1</documentId>" + 
                            "<name>" + documentName + "</name>" + 
                        "</document>" + 
                    "</documents>" +                        
                    "<recipients>" + 
                        "<signers>" + 
                            "<signer>" + 
                                "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" + 
                                "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +   
                                "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
                                "<clientUserId>1</clientUserId>" +
                                "<tabs>" +
                                        "<signHereTabs>" +
                                                "<signHere>" +
                                                "<anchorString>By:</anchorString>" +
                                                "<anchorXOffset>1</anchorXOffset>" +
                                                "<anchorYOffset>0</anchorYOffset>" +
                                                "<anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>" +
                                                "<anchorUnits>inches</anchorUnits>" +
                                                "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                                                "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                                                "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
                                            "</signHere>" +
                                        "</signHereTabs>" +
                                        "<dateSignedTabs>" +
                                                "<dateSigned>" +
                                                "<anchorString>(Date)</anchorString>" +
                                                "<anchorXOffset>1</anchorXOffset>" +
                                                "<anchorYOffset>-0.25</anchorYOffset>" +
                                                "<anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>" +
                                                "<anchorUnits>inches</anchorUnits>" +
                                                "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                                                "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                                                "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
                                            "</dateSigned>" +
                                        "</dateSignedTabs>" +
                                        "<textTabs>" +
                                                "<textTab>" +
                                                "<tabLabel>Data Field 1</tabLabel>" +
                                                    "<locked>false</locked>" +
                                                    "<xPosition>200</xPosition>" +
                                                    "<yPosition>200</yPosition>" +
                                                    "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                                                    "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                                                    "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
                                                    "<name>Text</name>" +
                                                    "<required>true</required>" +
                                                    "<value>Text</value>" +
                                                "</textTab>" +
                                        "</textTabs>" +                     
                                "</tabs>" +                   
                            "</signer>" + 
                        "</signers>" + 
                    "</recipients>" +  
                "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the inner xml element name to just `<text>` for each data tab you want.  So change to this:

```
"<textTabs>" +
    "<text>" +
    ...
```

Comment: @Ergin, while creating envelope I am setting the templateId in the envelopDefinition object, the template is already there in my docusign account, along with this i am sending some dynamic parameters as a list of Text, this list is wrapped inside a Tabs Object. I wanted to populate the table properties in the template with these dynamically passed parameters, but couldn't do it so far.
please provide an insight.

Comment: Please post a new question on Stack Overflow (under the `DocuSignAPI` tag) with a sample of the envelope you are building...